# Maximizing the integral of a transformation that depends on a neighborhood of values of the original function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, functional-equations, applied-mathematics

---

I'm not an expert in analysis whatsoever, so I might be posing a well-established question, or even an unanswerable one. Also, any suggestion on changes that might make the problem better are welcome.

We are working with interval-valued real functions over $\mathbb{R}^2$ (*i.e.*, $[0,1]^{\mathbb{R}^2}$). We have on our hands a *kernel* $k$ which is a functional over non-negative functions on a ball $\mathcal{B}_r$ around the origin with radius $r$. A couple of assumptions on $k$:

1. It is isotropic; *i.e.* it's value is stable when composing its argument with rotations ($k(f) = k(f \circ R_\theta)$).
2. It's monotonic; *i.e.*, it's value is monotonic in relation to the **norm** (integral) of the argument function ($\int_{\mathcal{B}_r} f \geq \int_{\mathcal{B}_r} f' \implies k(f) \geq k(f')$).

The problem is that of maximizing the following integral:

$$
\int_U k(f \circ \tau_x) dx
$$

over some nice region $U$ under the restriction that the integral of $f$ is some constant

$$
\int_U f(x) dx = K
$$

where $\tau_x$ is just a translation by $x$:

\begin{align*}
\tau_x &: \mathcal{B}_r \to \mathbb{R}^2 \\
\tau_x &: u \mapsto u + x
\end{align*}

---

Someone pointed to me the similarity to the problems in the calculus of variations, so that's where I went. But the problem is that, *e.g.*, in the Euler-Lagrange equation, the thing under the integral

$$
\int L(t, q(t), q'(t)) dt
$$

is a function $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ -- *i.e.*, it's strictly local, in that its value depends on the values of its argument and its derivatives *on a single point*, while my kernel $k$ depends on a whole neighborhood of values of the point.

I *think* this is my problem. Perhaps something is not clear, and the problem can be reduced to something more standard, by I can't see it.

The question is, more explicitly: how can I maximize the given integral expression under the given restriction? The goal is to have the most general assumptions on $k$ possible.

---

**Where did this come from?**

We're trying to model how vegetation distribution affects so-called ecological services around an urban area. The functions on $U$ represent the density of vegetation, and $k$ represents the way the vegetation affects, *e.g.*, the drop in temperature around it. We assume the effect is isotropic and local (all covered by the formalism). The question is: given a fixed amount of vegetation, what's the better way of distributing it around the city? Clumped together? In parks? In squares? All over the streets? One big forest? Etc.

Comment: Something seems wrong here. You are dealing with values of the form $f(u+x)$, where $u\in\mathcal B_r$ and $x\in U$. But then $u+x$ may be outside $U$, whereas $f$ seems to be defined on $U$.  I think the post requires some work.

Comment: Yeah, you're right; that's a problem in modelling. Data is always given in a limited region, but that's not a good physical assumption. Maybe a good way to fix it is to allow the functions to be defined all-over, but then maximize the integrals over $U$.

Comment: You still have $U$, now undefined. Also, by "circle", do you mean "disk"?

Comment: Yes. Corrected it. About $U$: yes, I leave any necessary assumptions for others to impose, when answering. Since I have no experience with this kind of problem, I can't fathom what's reasonable.